# How can I randomize the entry guard?

Tags: circuit, attacks, guard

Tor is moving to a single entry node implementation ([#11480](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11480)). I think that's because it's statistically feasible for an adversary to deploy entry and exit nodes and perform a correlation attack by profiling your use of those resources — sooner or later you'd end up using those nodes at least once.

Regardless of this circumstance I'd like to be able to quickly randomize the entry of a circuit programmatically. How can I do this? My guess is telnet tor daemon and send some commands, or is there a better/quicker way to accomplish that? If I correctly understood [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1452/1052) deleting the `state` file would be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting `/Applications/Tor Browser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/state` is a quick way. For creating circuits, refer to [tor control protocol](https://www.thesprawl.org/research/tor-control-protocol/).